# How to fetch "keyboard layout indicator" when it get disappeared

Tags: unity, indicator, layout

I'm not a native born English speaker. So I write in two languages on the web.
I added both layout (English and the other) and it works good. When I log out the system and log in again, "keyboard layout indicator" get disappeared and I'm not able to change keyboard layout even by using keyboard shortcut (Alt + Shift)

my question is :
How can i fetch "keyboard layout indicator" again to be able to switch between layouts?
What is the name of "keyboard layout indicator" (to exec in terminal)?

Comment: it is solved now

Comment: Can you please tell us how you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added other layout (Persian) again, when it got disappeared (when i logged out the system).
Now it works normal. 
I can switch between layouts when system get on after any logging out

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open system setting (`gnome-control-center` ) and select keyboard layout. In "layout" tab click on "options" and select "key(s) to change layout". Now you can select any key combination to change keyboard layout.
If you have trouble doing this, explain more about the problem.

Comment: Let me make it more clear. it`s not about the combination keys. it`s about not being able to use the combination to change the layout. the combination is sat and perfectly work til logging out. the indicator get disappear and combination stop working